# Executing a shell scripts that takes an input during execution with Java

Tags: java, bash, shell

I am trying to execute shell script in Java. I was able to achieve this in the following manner.

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/path_to/my_script.sh");
        pb.redirectOutput(new File("/new_path/out.txt"));
        Process p = pb.start();
        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How would I give user input if the shell requires user input?
How to implement this?

example: my_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter your name : " name
echo "Hi, $name. Let us be friends!"
```

I need to give input of name through Java.

Comment: Do you need to provide user input only when the script is launched in order to pass arguments to your script or while it is running ?

Comment: while its running

Answer (score 1):

EDIT following comments

```
    // writing to file
    String input = "Bob";
    try ( PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( filename ) ) {
        out.print( input );
    }

    // redirecting input from file
    pb.redirectInput( new File( filename ) );
    pb.redirectOutput( Redirect.INHERIT );
```

Initial answer;

Depending on how it is launch, following may be sufficient

```
pb.redirectInput( Redirect.INHERIT );
```

However to see message, output should also be redirected to std out

```
pb.redirectOutput( Redirect.INHERIT );
```

and tee output maybe done from shell

```
exec 6>&1 1> >(tee /new_path/out.txt)  # start tee output to out.txt (save current output to file descriptor 6 for example)
...
exec >&6      # end to restore standard output and terminate tee process
```

Note about InterruptedException, it should not be catched and continue the program, but propagated until point where task is really finished.

Comment: Could you please elaborate.. I didn't quite understand.

Comment: what did not you understand ? And how do you launch java program ?

Comment: I am running this on a java server, with javaEE

Comment: if you need to pass input while it's running you can't use System.in, how will you give input from client to server?

Comment: I can't change the script. I can take the input from the client side through request ajax call.

Comment: How would I do it if I were to use System.in?

Comment: Lets say I have it stored in a Variable?

Comment: if whole input is known when calling the shell a file could be created with content and passed in redirectInput

Comment: Could you please write a sample code of how that would be implemented?

Comment: Thank you so much Nahuel  :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can do it like below:-

```
 String inputName = "blabla";
 String command = "/path_to/my_script.sh  " + inputName;
 Process p;
 try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now you have to modify your shell script like below:-

```
#!/bin/bash
#read -p "Enter your name : " name
name = $1
echo "Hi, $name. Let us be friends!"
```

Comment: @Abhijith Pritam I want it to take input where in I can't modify the shell script. Can you suggest any ways of doing that?

Comment: No idea. Try with below answer.